# Extending Craft Commerce Purchasable Nav Items

Tags: craft3, php, plugin-craftcommerce2

I'm looking to extend Craft Commerce with a custom Purchasable.

I'd like to implement this using a module if possible.

I've implemented the base class for my new Purchasable and that's all good.

What I'm wondering is can I add this new Purchasable type to the Commerce `cpNavItem` list?

My new Purchasable extends the base Purchasable class as follows:
`class Donation extends Purchasable` and I'm registering using the following Events:

```
Event::on(Purchasables::class, Purchasables::EVENT_REGISTER_PURCHASABLE_ELEMENT_TYPES, function(RegisterComponentTypesEvent $event) {
            $event->types[] = CustomPurchasable::class;
        });

Event::on(Elements::class, Elements::EVENT_REGISTER_ELEMENT_TYPES, function(RegisterComponentTypesEvent $e) {
            $e->types[] = CustomPurchasable::class;
        });
```

I know that if I go the plugin route I can register a new control panel nav section but I'd like to avoid that if possible and keep this new Purchasable inside of the Commmerce nav section.

kind regards,

piaras